# My concurrent code is synchronised but it is not printing values in sync however each thread prints the same value

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization, java.util.concurrent

I am trying to demonstrate how to fix a RaceCondition using the synchronized keyword. The below code consists of a ZooStock objects' variable being incremented and printed by 4 threads. I have synchronized the method (addGrass()) however the values being printed by all threads are the same i.e.

Current output:  `1002g, 1002g, 1002g, 1002g`

Expected output:  `1001g, 1002g, 1003g, 1004g`

```
  public static void main(String[] args){
          ZooStockSync zooStockNew = new ZooStockSync(1000, 750, 5000);
          ExecutorService executorService = null;
          try{
              executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10); //Creating a Thread pool of size 10
              for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
                  executorService.submit(()->new ZooWorkerSync(zooStockNew).addGrass()); //
              }
          }finally{
              if(executorService != null) executorService.shutdown();
          }
      }
```

Class containing synchronized method:

```
class ZooWorkerSync implements Runnable {

        ZooStockSync zooStock;

        ZooWorkerSync(ZooStockSync zooStock){
            this.zooStock = zooStock;
        }

        public synchronized void addGrass(){
            zooStock.grass++;
            System.out.print(zooStock.grass + "g ");
        }
}
```

However when I create Threads in a traditional (java.lang.Thread) sense without using the Executor threads from java.util.concurrent package.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    ZooStockSync zooStockTraditional = new ZooStockSync(1000, 750, 5000);
    ZooWorkerSync[] workerThreads = new ZooWorkerSync[4]; //Set all elements in the array to be a ZooWorker object
    Arrays.fill(workerThreads, new ZooWorkerSync(zooStockTraditional));
    for (ZooWorkerSync workerThread : workerThreads) {
        new Thread(workerThread).start(); //Start the worker threads off (this invokes the run method in the ZooWorker class)
    }
  }
```

The output is as expected: `1001g 5010w 751h 1002g 5020w 752h 1003g 5030w 753h 1004g 5040w 754h`, notice the g's are in ascending order as expected. (Ignore the h's and w's)

The worker thread's run method is shown below:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    addGrass();
    addWater();
    addHay();
}
```

So my question is, why do the 2 outputs differ, why am I getting the same value printed using the java.util.concurent Executors' threads opposed to the traditional method?

Comment: `synchronized` on a method means you're synchronizing on the object itself, and since you created 4 different `ZooWorkerSync` objects, one for each thread, synchronizing the method has no effect.

Comment: What do you think `Arrays.fill(workerThreads, new ZooWorkerSync(zooStockTraditional));` does? A hint: Not filling the array with a new instance per index.

Comment: @akuzminykh Hey, so I believe Arrays.fill() basically sets each index of the array to be populated with the same instance of ZooWorkerSync, I believe in the example where I use the executor threads I created a new instance. I shouldn't of done this as synchronized is used as an instance level lock, hence across multiple instances the synchronization is redundant. I need 1 instance and multiple threads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `ExeutorService` example, you're creating multiple instances of the `ZooWorkerSync` class, in the `Thread` example you're reusing the same instance.

In your first example, the `synchronized` keyword doesn't really do anything since it's an instance level lock. You could try manually synchronizing on the class instead.

Answer (score 3):

`synchronized` locks an object, and because you are sync'ing on multiple object, it isn't working as you'd like.

Instead, you should synchronize on a common object, like the class.

```
class ZooWorkerSync implements Runnable {

        ZooStockSync zooStock;

        ZooWorkerSync(ZooStockSync zooStock){
            this.zooStock = zooStock;
        }

        public void addGrass(){
            synchronized (ZooWorkerSync.class) {
              zooStock.grass++;
              System.out.print(zooStock.grass + "g ");
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the code for ZooStockSync but it looks like you're synchronizing a method on the thread (ZooWorkerSync) and not the object being shared. You then access a field in ZooStockSync:

```
 public synchronized void addGrass(){
        zooStock.grass++;
        System.out.print(zooStock.grass + "g ");
    }
```

But access to that field (grass) may not be thread safe. Each ZooWorkerSync thread can access that field simultaneously. I would suggest putting synchronized on a method in ZooStockSync that increments the field. For example:

```
public synchronized void incrementGrass() {
     grass++;
}
```

You can also use the volatile keyword for the grass field, or make it an [AtomicInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html).

Answer (score 0):

The error arises from me creating several instances of ZooWorkerSync in the Executors example, the use of the word synchronized as demonstrated above works as an instance level lock, so it is practically redundant across multiple instances, it will only be useful for a single instance, hence I need to modify my executorService to only invoke addGrass() from a single instance:

```
  public static void main(String[] args){
          ZooStockSync zooStockNew = new ZooStockSync(1000, 750, 5000);
          ExecutorService executorService = null;
          try{
              executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10); //Creating a Thread pool of size 10
              ZooWorkerSync zooWorkerSync = new ZooWorkerSync(zooStockNew);
              for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
                  executorService.submit(zooWorkerSync::addGrass);
              }
          }finally{
              if(executorService != null) executorService.shutdown();
          }
  }
```